# Nest.js: Connection is not released if rule-based exception thrown from Multer, FilesInterceptor decorator

Tags: nestjs, multer

I have a Nest.js application that accepts one or more image file uploads (multipart/form-data).
The controller:

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('image')) 
public async initiate( 
  @Res() res: Response, @UploadedFiles() images?: Array<Express.Multer.File>): Promise<void> { 
     let retCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED; 
     res.status(retCode).send(); 
}
```

The module code where the MulterModule is being registered is:

```
@Module(
{ 
  imports: [ 
     MulterModule.registerAsync({ useClass: MulterConfig }) 
  ],
  controllers: [TestController],
  providers: [Logger, TestService] 
}) 
export class TestModule {}
```

The MulterConfig class is:

```
@Injectable() 
export class MulterConfig implements MulterOptionsFactory { 
  constructor() {} 
  public createMulterOptions(): MulterModuleOptions { 
    return { 
            limits: 
            { 
                files: 1 
            }, 
            fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => { 
                console.log(`Filetype is: ${file.mimetype}`); 
                if(file.mimetype === 'image/png') { 
                    callback(null, true); 
                } else { 
                    callback(new BadRequestException('asdfasdf'), false); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Lastly, the global exception filter that I registered in main.ts:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new TestExceptionFilter());
```

...and the filter itself:

```
import { Catch, ExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost } from "@nestjs/common"; 
import { Request, Response } from 'express';  

@Catch() 
export class TestExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter { 
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {        
      console.log('in exception filter');
      let status = 500;     
      const ctx = host.switchToHttp();  
      const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>(); 
      response.status(status).send(); 

      //response.destroy(new Error('forcing stream destruction')); 
    } 
}
```

I have observed that if any of the Multer rules are violated, like if I send more than one file via Postman or Insomnia with this rule in place:

`... limits: { files: 1 }, ...`

Multer will raise an exception "Too Many Files". 
This gets caught by the global exception filter.  However, I notice that the connection does not really terminate, so if I try to send the request again via Postman, the app is hung.

If I timeout after 60 seconds or if I cancel the request and try it again, it works.
The net effect is that it only works every other request. Here is the exception output emitted to the console:

```
Filetype is: image/png
in top-level exception filter
exception type is: BadRequestException
BadRequestException: Too many files
    at transformException (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+core@10.0.0/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/multer/multer/multer.utils.js:20:20)
    at /Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+core@10.0.0/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/multer/interceptors/files.interceptor.js:21:73
    at done (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:45:7)
    at /Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:65:11
    at /Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/remove-uploaded-files.js:20:9
    at MemoryStorage._removeFile (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/storage/memory.js:16:3)
    at remove (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:58:19)
    at handleFile (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/remove-uploaded-files.js:10:5)
    at removeUploadedFiles (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/remove-uploaded-files.js:25:3)
    at Counter.<anonymous> (/Users/landerson/Develop/repos/claims-ai-svc/node_modules/.pnpm/multer@1.4.4-lts.1/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:61:9) {
  response: { message: 'Too many files', error: 'Bad Request', statusCode: 400 },
  status: 400,
  options: {}
}
in exception filter!
```

Now, if I uncomment the last line in the global exception filter:

```
 //response.destroy(new Error('forcing connection destruction'));
```

The app forces the termination of the connection and it works successfully, save for the who-knows-what-bad-things-will-happen-later because of the forced termination of the connection.

Why is this happening? What dumb thing did I do (or didn't do)?

To be clear this just one project, no other package.json's involved. My dependencies:

```
    "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/terminus": "^10.0.1",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.0",
    "nest-winston": "^1.9.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "winston": "^3.10.0"
```

Things I have tried: Using the latest 9.x version of Nest's libraries, which exhibit the same hang.

I have also tried implementing Multer in (nest) middleware, have created my own files interceptor, created an second interceptor to "wrap" the first interceptor to trap and rethrow exceptions and have tried various other gyrations of complete futility.

All of my alternative solutions exhibit the same problem. After Googling the entirety of the Internet (and nest's GitHub pages), it seems I am the only one on the planet to see this problem, which leads me to believe I'm doing something dumb.

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Comment: I found that if I add a header to the response in the exception filter:
`response.status(status).header('Connection', 'close').send()`

Postman and Insomnia honor it and close the connection.

I'm not at the point of answering my own question because I do not understand why/how this is happening in the first place.

And of course response.destroy(), response.socket.end(), response.socket.destroy() work, but I would prefer not to rely on these.